# _afterLoad() on models when loading collection

Tags: collection, model

I've defined some logic in the `_afterLoad()` for one of my models. When loading one model using `Mage::getModel('foo/bar)->load(1)` `_afterLoad()` is triggered and the extra data values are set. When loading a collection, though, `_afterLoad` is not triggered on every model. How can I make it work that a collection returns its models with `_afterLoad()` automatically executed?

Answer (score 4):

The `_afterLoad` method in the models is not meant to be loaded when the collection is loaded.
But there is an [`_afterLoad`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php#L678) method available for db collections also.
You can use that to implement your logic for a collection load.

Comment: That's lame ;p So in the collection _afterLoad() method you would loop over the loaded models and then you would call the public function afterLoad() on all of these models, right?